# Include an image into a "mailto" mail?

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, mailto

The title might not be clear - I'm creating an app in `Unity` and I want it to start the device's default mail client to create a new mail. I can easily do that with `mailto`. What I don't know how to do is include an image in the mail being composed. In any way: as an attachment, as a part of the mail body or whatever. But it's a local image, so I can't just put a link to it in the mail.

Is it even possible? If so, how?

Comment: I said I wanted to use the device's default mail client. The solution from your link requires providing SMTP host address - what would that be? Can it even work on a mobile device?

Comment: If you are developing for iOS/Android have a look at the [Etecetera Plugin from Prime31](http://prime31.com/docs#iosEtc). There is a _showMailComposerWithAttachment_ method (haven't tried it out yet)

Comment: Actually, I'd like it to work on Flash too. But Etcetera plugin might be **some** way to go, thx.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if you can do it as the mailto page doesn't mention this as one of the parameters.
At best you can add body and subject.No attachments I suppose
See http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2368.html

However a hack you can try is in the body that you include
add `<img src="your image src">` and hopefully the mail client will recognise this as html markup and render the image when the client opens up.

I haven't tried this though.

Comment: I know that `mailto` doesn't have attachments, I need some other way of doing that. And - no, your hack doesn't work.